# laravel 4.1 Form with controller action dosent route to correct route

Tags: php, forms, laravel, url-routing

I have a form which should go to the `TestsController` Controller and it's `takeTest` method, this is the code below that generated the `form`:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'TestsController@takeTest')) }}
```

The generated `HTML`:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://192.168.0.8/tests" accept-charset="UTF-8"
```

The routes declared in `routes.php` file:

```
Route::get('tests', 'TestsController@index');

Route::post('tests', 'TestsController@takeTest');

Route::post('tests', 'TestsController@processMarking');
```

It should go to `takeTest` method but it goes to the `processMarking` method instead. Why is this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: How do you expect it to differentiate between two routes with the same uri and request method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have declared two routes using same `URI/tests` and same method (`post`) like this:

```
Route::post('tests', 'TestsController@takeTest'); // first

Route::post('tests', 'TestsController@processMarking'); // second
```

So the second `route` is overriding the first `route`. If you change the `URI` of your second `route` to something else then it'll work, for example:

```
Route::post('moretests', 'TestsController@processMarking');
```

You can't use same `URI` for two routes using same method (i.e. `post` in your case).

Comment: I would of thought the Controller action would match against the same one in the routes. Otherwise what is the point of stating a controller action in the form?

Comment: The `'action' => 'TestsController@takeTest'` generated `action="http://192.168.0.8/tests"` `URI` as `action`.

Comment: When you have used `Form::open(array('action' => 'TestsController@takeTest'))` it searched for `value` in the `RouteCollection` object and found `tests` as the key for `TestsController@takeTest`, that's it.

Comment: Cheers for the explanation and answer.